# Is meat Rajasik or Tamasik?

Tags: dharma, food, gunas

Some call it Rajasik. Some call it Tamasik. Is meat mentioned as Rajasik or Tamasik food in our texts?

Comment: @NogShine didn't get any answer to my question there. My question is specific. Do texts consider meat as Rajasik or Tamasik?

Comment: Its a disputed matter. Some say Rajasic (mainly RKM monks) while others say Tamasic. The commonly accepted view is that its Tamasic. I too personally find it Tamasic. The dispute isn't a surprise though. Many other food items such as eggplants are disputed.

Comment: Meat is considered tamasic as it takes very long to digest. I have heard from a knowledgeable person that spicy foods are considered rajasic.